# rsyncd service ProtectSystem=off has no effect

Tags: systemd, rsync

I'm running Debian 11 with rsyncd 3.2, which has `ProtectSystem=full` as default.

I'd like to override that, so am using `systemctl edit` to do so. Here's what I'm putting in the override:

```
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/rsync.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of the file

[Service]
ProtectSystem=off

### Lines below this comment will be discarded
```

The logs report no parsing errors with this and the unit (I think) reloads with the new configuration.

However, I still get "Read-only file system" errors when trying to rsync in to paths in `/etc` (for example).

What is wrong that I can't override this restriction? Or is this restriction not the issue? The configuration was working fine on Debian 10 before I upgraded to Debian 11, so I assume it the `ProtectSystem` that's causing the problem.

EDIT: Here's the config in `/etc/rsyncd.conf` I'm using:

```
[nameOfMount]
     path = /etc/postfix
     auth users = sysadmin
     secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
     hosts allow = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
     read only = false
     uid = root
     pre-xfer exec = /usr/local/bin/scriptA.sh
     post-xfer exec = /usr/local/bin/scriptB.sh
```

The pro/post exec scripts make backup copies of files being transferred, and reload the postfix daemon. The errors from these are for example:

```
rsync error: requested action not supported (code 4) at clientserver.c(1098) [Receiver=3.2.3]
/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/postfix/fileName.yyyymmddd': Read-only file system
```

Comment: Yes, it has a mount on /etc/postfix, hence the "read only" errors when I try connecting to that I think. Other mounts (eg to /opt) work fine. - I'll post the config though if that's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a status check

```
systemctl show rsync | grep -E 'ProtectSystem|NoNewPrivileges'
```

On my unmodified system this returns

```
ProtectSystem=full
NoNewPrivileges=yes
```

I've picked up on `NoNewPrivileges` because this setting prevents `rsyncd` changing its UID.

Now let's look at the time that the `rsync` daemon was restarted, and make a note of it (22:53 in my case):

```
ps -ef | grep '[r]sync --daemon'

root     22600     1  0 22:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
```

If I add your two lines to the override,

```
systemctl edit rsync

[Service]
ProtectSystem=off
```

I then get this

```
systemctl show rsync | grep -E 'ProtectSystem|NoNewPrivileges'

ProtectSystem=no
NoNewPrivileges=yes
```

But the `rsync` daemon is not restarted:

```
ps -ef | grep '[r]sync --daemon'

root     22600     1  0 22:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
```

And indeed I find I must do this manually

```
systemctl restart rsync
ps -ef | grep '[r]sync --daemon'

root     22770     1  1 22:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
```

However, the filesystem is still in read-only mode. We need the extra line:

```
systemctl edit rsync

[Service]
ProtectSystem=off
NoNewPrivileges=no
```

Followed by a restart,

```
systemctl restart rsync
```

And a final sanity-check,

```
systemctl show rsync | grep -E 'ProtectSystem|NoNewPrivileges'
```

On my system this returns the desired end game, which allows me to write to files and directories underneath `/etc`:

```
ProtectSystem=no
NoNewPrivileges=no
```

Comment: Thank you for cluing me that the problem was not just with the `ProtectSystem`. In my case (the default for Debian 11?), I also had `PrivateDevices=on` which was also stopping the desired behaviour.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts I didn't find that a stopper. Raspbian here (derived from Debian)

Comment: Maybe it's because I switched to using `ReadWritePaths` instead of turning off `ProtectSystem` and `NoNewPrivileges`?  `PrivateDevices` appears to prevent writing to physical devices like /dev/sda, for example. Maybe I should look at `DeviceAllow` too?

Comment: Why would you want to write to a device?

Comment: `/dev/sda` is the block device (disk) on which my desired path is on.

Comment: You definitely _do not_ want to write to `/dev/sda`. You'll destroy your entire filesystem if you succeed

Comment: OK maybe some misunderstanding then, but it's all back working OK as it was, so no matter.